# Where can I find this "history" symbol as character?

Tags: html, text, unicode

Does anyone know where I can find this "history" symbol as character? I wanna use it for a HTML button.

[image: history symbol]

Comment: I believe there is no such character in the Unicode standard, but take a look at the [Unicode Character Name Index](https://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html).

Comment: Ehm, is that a png with a black foreground on a transparent background. I'm using the dark theme, see, and it's hard to make out.

Answer (score 0):

You can download that icon from here:
https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/352426/history_icon